# how to set toolbar color in tabris.js (a mobile development framework)

Tags: android

On my android 4.4, toolbar always shows dark. I want to set it as the same color as the tabfolder, so that they seem like a whole. Anyone knows how to do that> Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can colorize the toolbar by setting the `background` property of the `tabris.ui` to a color.

See https://tabrisjs.com/documentation/1.0/api/ui